# How to make part of the private base class's methods public?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11

For example, I have a base class with a number of methods

```
class A
{
public:
    void f1();
    int f2() const;
    float f3(double a, char b) const;
    ...
};
```

And a class B is privately derived from A. I want to some of A's methods are public, how to do it?

```
class B : private A
{
public:
    using A::f1; 
    using A::f2;

    template<class... Args>
    RETURN f3(Args&&... args) CONSTNESS  { return A::f3(args...); }
    // how to specify return and constness automatically

    ... 
};
```

I try the above ways, they don't work. The template way need to specify return and constness automatically.

Asked the wrong question, in my real case, A is a template class

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    void f1();
    int f2() const;
    float f3(double a, char b) const;
    ...
};
```

B is derived from A

```
 template<class T>
 class B : public A
 {
 public:
     using A::f1; // wrong
     using A<T>::f1; // okay
 };
```

Comment: The `using A::f1` should work. What compiler do you use?

Answer (score 5):

The `using A::f1` should work, but it will expose all functions called f1 in A. If you don't want this you need to create a proxy for each function you want to expose

The trick with your template

```
template<class... Args>
RETURN f3(Args&&... args) CONSTNESS  { return A::f3(args...); }
```

can be done only with meta program, but it would not work anyway because you cannot overload a function on it's return type, so you cannot select the right function, unless you are willing to write `f3<float>` each time you are invoking the function.

You cannot 'specify' the return value and constness, because you are not specyfying anything. you create all possible f3 functions with different parameters and those that don't have a corresponding f3 in A will simply fail to compile when used.

But that's as far as you can go. if you create all f3 functions with all possible results, the compiler won't know witch one to call as you cannot overload a function on it's result.